# Next without For Error while adding new If functions VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I do not see where the mistake is.

this is currently my code:

```
For Each Rng3 In Range("$A$3:$A$1000")
If Rng3.Value = "Account Credit (Debit G/L)" Then
    If Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            GLIVR = GLIVR + 1
        Else: Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            GLManual = GLManual + 1
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
            EFGLManual = EFGLManual + 1
        End If
If Rng3.Value = "Account Credit (Debit G/L)" Then
    If Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
            GLIVR = GLIVR + 1
        Else: Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
     Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
            GLManual = GLManual + 1
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
            EFGLManual = EFGLManual + 1
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Next Rng3

I do not see where the error is.

This was the original code I tried to add code to:

```
For Each Rng3 In Range("$A$3:$A$1000")
If Rng3.Value = "Account Credit (Debit G/L)" Then
    If Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 50 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 50 Then
            GLIVR = GLIVR + 1
        Else: Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 50 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 50 Then
            GLManual = GLManual + 1
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 25 Then Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 25 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 25 Then
            EFGLManual = EFGLManual + 1
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Next Rng3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

@barrowc Thank you for this explanation it makes a lot of sense. Thanks to your recommendation I have solved the error but now there seems to be another issue with it. This is now the code:

```
'For Each Rng3 In Range("$A$3:$A$1000")
    If Rng3.Value = "Account Credit (Debit G/L)" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" Then
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
                GLIVR = GLIVR + 1
            Else: Rng3.ClearContents
            End If
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
        Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
                GLManual = GLManual + 1
            ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then Rng3.ClearContents
            End If
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
        Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
                EFGLManual = EFGLManual + 1
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" And _
        Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
                If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
                GLIVR = GLIVR + 1
            Else: Rng3.ClearContents
            End If
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
        Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
                GLManual = GLManual + 1
            ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then Rng3.ClearContents
            End If
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
        Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
                EFGLManual = EFGLManual + 1
            End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next Rng3
```

The new issue I am having is with the second part of the code which is :

```
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
            GLIVR = GLIVR + 1
        Else: Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
            GLManual = GLManual + 1
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then Rng3.ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
            EFGLManual = EFGLManual + 1
        End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Next Rng3

This part seems to do nothing to my results. The idea behind this code is that I want to clear the values below 250 when the column 5 is named "812-135". If the value is 250 or above, I want it to show just like the above lines do.
For "812-519" the code worked. Basically I want to have the same results that are shown under "812-519" to be shown under "812-135" but not for any value, only for values above or equal to 250. Currently with this code it shows all values under "812-135" (for example 2,3,5,109,111 etc.)

Comment: The problem is? What are you trying to achieve? Line that gives the error? Please note that the shorter and/or clearer the question the better we can help

Comment: Are you designing a space ship? Never seen so many level of nested ifs. I advice you to *re-think* your problem and to re-organize your code.

Comment: @sgva I have now fixed the error code thanks to barrowc 's comment. The purpose is to paste a set of data and have a macro with which filters out the rows that are the needed and the ones that are not. The idea behind the second part of the code mentioned above after my edit is that I want to clear the values below 250 when the column 5 is named "812-135". If the value is 250 or above, I want it to show just like the above lines under "812-519" do. Basically I want to have the same results that are shown under "812-519" to be shown under "812-135" but only for values >=250

Comment: I've updated my answer at the end with details of how to fix this additional problem. If you still have further issues then please create a new question rather than editing this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any control structure like `For Each... Next` must have the nesting level immediately prior to its opening statement be the same as the nesting level immediately after its closing statement. In the code given, immediately prior to the `For Each` part is at nesting level 0 but immediately after the `Next` part is at nesting level 3.

There need to be three more `End If` statements added but exactly where to add them depends on how your code should work. The indentation in the code given does not reflect the actual nesting levels. Parts of the given code reach seven levels of nesting which suggests that the code needs to be refactored.

Here's a simple nesting level example. This is OK (before and after levels are the same):

```
' nesting level 0
For Each a in b
    ' nesting level 1
    If a.Value > 5 Then
        ' nesting level 2
    End If
    ' nesting level 1
Next a
' nesting level 0
```

This is not OK (before and after levels are different for both the `For Each... Next` and `If... End If`):

```
' nesting level 0    
For Each a in b
    ' level 1
     If a.Value > 5 Then
         ' level 2
     Next a
     ' level 1
End If
' level 0
```

Looking at just the relevant part of your code:

```
' nesting level 0
For Each Rng3 In Range("$A$3:$A$1000")
    ' level 1
    If Rng3.Value = "Account Credit (Debit G/L)" Then
        ' level 2
        If Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" Then
            ' level 3
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
                ' level 4
            End If
            ' level 3 (but ElseIf acts at nesting level above)
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
        Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
            ' level 3
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
                ' level 4
            End If
            ' level 3 (but ElseIf acts at nesting level above)
        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
        Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-519" Then
            ' level 3
            If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 0 Then
                ' level 4
            End If
            ' level 3
            If Rng3.Value = "Account Credit (Debit G/L)" Then
                ' level 4
                If Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" Then
                    ' level 5
                    If Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
                        ' level 6
                        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
                            ' level 7
                        End If
                        ' level 6 (but ElseIf acts at level above)
                    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
                    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
                        ' level 6
                        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
                            ' level 7 (but ElseIf acts at level above)
                        ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then Rng3.ClearContents
                        End If
                        ' level 6 (but ElseIf acts at level above)
                    ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
                    Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
                        ' level 6
                        If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
                            ' level 7
                        End If
                        ' level 6
                    End If
                    ' level 5
                End If
                ' level 4
            Next rng3
            ' level 3
```

---

*edit:* the altered code is incorrect at this part:

```
If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
    GLManual = GLManual + 1
ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then Rng3.ClearContents
End If
```

The line which clears the contents only does so for values less than zero. For values between 0 and 249, no action is taken.

You could change the code to:

```
If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value = 250 Or Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value > 250 Then
    GLManual = GLManual + 1
ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value < 250 Then Rng3.ClearContents
End If
```

If you look at the values involved, however, every possible value of `Rng3.Offset(0, 1)` will satisfy either the If clause or the ElseIf clause. Therefore, the code should be written as:

```
If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value >= 250 Then
    GLManual = GLManual + 1
Else
    Rng3.ClearContents
End If
```

`x >= y` is a short form for `x > y Or x = y`

This eliminates two potential problems:

- unintentionally having values which aren't handled (you've already had this problem). Now any value will either satisfy the If clause or the Else clause
- updating some of the comparison values but not others (you've already had this problem). Now there is only one occurrence of the comparison value so this problem can't happen again for this `If... End If` block.

A further improvement would be to define and use constants for "magic numbers", like this:

```
' Near the start of the Sub or Function
Const LIMIT_812_135 As Integer = 250

' Use it like this
ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "IVR Risk" And _
Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
    If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value >= LIMIT_812_135 Then
        GLIVR = GLIVR + 1
    Else: Rng3.ClearContents
    End If
ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "No" And _
Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
    If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value >= LIMIT_812_135 Then
        GLManual = GLManual + 1
    Else
        Rng3.ClearContents
    End If
ElseIf Rng3.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Manual Risk" And Rng3.Offset(0, 9).Value = "Yes" And _
Rng3.Offset(0, 5).Value <> "812-135" Then
    If Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value >= LIMIT_812_135 Then
        EFGLManual = EFGLManual + 1
    End If
```

This prevents different values unintentionally being used for the same comparison throughout the code and also allows the comparison value to be changed just by editing the value of the constant

Comment: I have edited the post to add more comments on the issue. Apologies if that is not how to do it I couldn't figure out how to reply with enough space to write all the code. Thanks